# InstallShield 5.5 - Where to find boxed licensed copy

Tags: vb6, windows-xp, installshield

A project I worked on 15+ years ago as need additional work. Unfortunately, my build & kit environment has long ago been taken down. I have recreated the build environment but am seeking a boxed, licensed copy of InstallShield 5.5. Does anyone know where I can find one. I have the old .ipr files but updating it to a newer Install Shield has proven very difficult. I just want it to work again and allow me to generate a self extracting .exe. I'm doing this all on an old XP laptop with VS6 and VB6. Everything compiles and links. Just need to create a kit. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Ideas:

- Look on [eBay](http://ebay.com) - it typically has lots of obsolete items like this. You can search internationally and also save your search so it will email you when new matches are found. (I don't see any copies on there as of this moment).
- Contact the current InstallShield owner - [Flexera Software](https://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/). Maybe they can help you out.
- Post on [VBForums](http://www.vbforums.com/forumdisplay.php?1-Visual-Basic-6-and-Earlier) - possibly someone has a copy they can sell/send/lend you.
- Depending on your comfort level, you might find it on a download site / torrent download site. Since you do own a license this seems legit to me, but you need to be careful of malware, etc. (especially since you will presumably distribute the results of this installer build).

Comment: Good answer. I too would be very wary of malware from a download / torrent site. I would also suggest setting up a virtual machine with XP / VB6 / InstallShield just in case the old laptop hardware dies...

Comment: Use the Package and Deployment Wizard to get the list of dependancies and then use Inno Setup to create an installer.